# Increase margin for Impact stats on child meta profiles

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, per-site-meta

There's (to my taste) a bit too little margin between 'people reached' and 'posts edited' on [child meta profiles](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4808/glorfindel?tab=topactivity) (left) when compared to [main site profiles](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/users/4808/glorfindel?tab=topactivity) (right). It feels kind of cluttered right now:

[image]
[image]

This is probably related to the absence of a reputation graph and privilege tracker in the leftmost block.

Comment: Thanks @Nimesh, I always forget one's own profile opens on a different tab than other users' profiles ...